# Connect to two bluetooth audio sinks

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I have two bluetooth audio receivers, one in the living room, and one in my bedroom. I connect to those from my laptop. Both receivers are visible from most places in my house. My plan is that I connect to both, and then use pavucontrol to select which audio goes to which receiver. So I don't want to send the same audio to both receivers; I just want to send the audio to the living room receiver when I'm in the living room, and to the bedroom receiver when I'm in the bedroom.

Both receivers are trusted and I can connect to either of them without problems, and I can use pavucontrol to send the audio to the receiver. So in principle, everything works. However, I can only connect to one device at any time, and not to both devices simultaneously. When I turn on my laptop, it will connect to one of the two receivers, and then it keeps on trying to connect to the other, but it fails with a message in the systemlog:

```
Apr 02 23:17:20 kitten bluetoothd[357]: Unable to select SEP
```

Searching the internet for that message gave suggestions to add some things to /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf, which didn't exist on my system so I created it with the following contents:

```
[General]
MaxConnected=2
Disable=Socket

[A2DP]
SBCSources=2
```

This doesn't make any difference at all. Does anyone have a clue, or suggestions on to search for? I'm using Arch Linux btw.